# Why am I getting these strange C# 8 "nullable reference types" warnings: Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value before exiting constructor.?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-8.0

I'm trying to get a handle on C# 8's new nullable compiler checks. The following struct is giving me some strange warnings.

```
// This struct gives no warnings
public struct Thing<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    Thing(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = value is { };
    }
}

// This struct gives warning on the constructor:
// "Non-nullable field "_value" must contain a non-null value before exiting constructor.
// Consider declaring the field as nullable.
public struct Thing<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    Thing(T value)
    ~~~~~
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = _value is { };
    }
}

// This struct gives two warnings, one on the constructor and one on `_value = value`
// [1] "Non-nullable field "_value" must contain a non-null value before exiting constructor.
// Consider declaring the field as nullable.
// [2] Possible null reference assignment.
// This is true even if I check value for null and throw an ArgumentNullException before the assignment.
public struct Thing<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    Thing(T value)
    ~~~~~ // [1]
    {
        _hasValue = value is { };
        _value = value;
                 ~~~~~ // [2]
    }
}
```

Have I created some impossible situation where the compiler can't figure out the intent? Is this a compiler bug related to nullable reference types in constructors? What am I missing here?

Comment: I suspect that [notnull](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters#notnull-constraint) only applies to consumers of the generic type but not to code inside...

Comment: Did you mean an "is object" check?

Comment: The first non-working example makes sense to me, as given the rules for initialization, the guarantee of non-null for the field can only be made _after_ the constructor has returned. The actual error message is unfortunate, but that an error might occur seems reasonable. The second non-working example, makes a lot less sense to me; I don't have a good justification for that off the top of my head (otherwise I'd post an answer about both). I would not be surprised if both are compiler bugs, and possible already reported. Did you check the github repo?

Answer (score 5):

All of these scenarios make perfect sense to me. Let's look at each one, but first let's agree on some things:

- Non-nullable/nullable reference types aren't real types. They are just annotations the compiler knows how to interpret
- The struct is constrained to `notnull` however someone can pass a `null` reference to it, without any warnings if they have not enabled nullable analysis (`#nullable enable`)
- `val is {}` is a `null` test. By using it, you imply that the value *can* be `null`
- The compiler uses flow analysis. It looks for various patterns to determine the state of a value. It will **take your word** that something can be/isn't `null` and it will use previous assignments as proof of a variable's nullability even when it might not make sense

  - This is the one that's the kicker here. It doesn't make sense to *us* that the field of a not fully-constructed object can be changed from one line to the next; there's not two threads changing values. But the compiler isn't human-smart and will defer to us when we tell it that we know better
- Under most (all?) circumstances, flow analysis does not work backwards, meaning that an asserted state on line `N` does not impact line `N-1`

Let's look at the examples:

```cs
public struct ThingA<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    ThingA(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = value is { };
    }
}
```

`ThingA` emits no warnings. You've constrained to `notnull` and assigned to `_value`. Prior to this you've not performed any nullability assertions so the compiler assumes that up to this point the parameter is in fact not `null` *per the contract*. Flow analysis doesn't work backwards. Assigning to `_hasValue` using a `null` test against the parameter only affects the *future* nullable state of the `value` *parameter*. The compiler doesn't say "hey I remembered using `value` to assign to something, let me go fix up everything"--that'd be too much work. Now we exit the constructor and you've not reassigned the `_value` field so its previously decided state of "not null" remains. No warnings.

```cs
public struct ThingB<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    ThingB(T value)
    {
        _value = value;
        _hasValue = _value is { };
    }
}
```

`ThingB` starts out with a similar flow to `ThingA`. Because we have no previous `null` tests and we have a `notnull` constraint on T, assigning to the `_value` field reinforces its non-null state per the contract. But here's where it gets tricky! You now perform a `null` test against the very same field, thus implying that it *could* in fact be `null`. Flow analysis doesn't work backwards so we don't get a warning on the line assigning to the field, but you have told the compiler that the field's state could be `null`. We're exiting the constructor with a possibly `null` field. Here's your warning.

```cs
public struct ThingC<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    ThingC(T value)
    {
        _hasValue = value is { };
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

For `ThingC`, you perform a `null` check on the parameter, implying it *can* be `null`. The parameter's `null` state is changed to "maybe null" You then use that parameter when assigning to `_value`. Well you just said it *can* be `null`, but per the constraint it can't be. Here's the first warning. Now we leave the constructor body and the field's state is still "maybe null" (per the assignment). There's the second warning.

In the comments you state

> This is true even if I check value for null and throw an
> ArgumentNullException before the assignment.

Well, that's only true depending on *where* you place the check. Consider this:

```cs
public struct ThingD<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    ThingD(T value)
    {
         if (value is null) throw new Exception();
        _hasValue = value is { };
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

Under normal circumstances, flow analysis would catch this. Except this suffers the same problem as `ThingC`: you're telling the compiler that the parameter still (somehow!) *can* be `null` in your `_hasValue` assignment/`null` test. You get the same warning. [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8igWACgABAJgEYnmBmC2BfAGMYFACoALAJa4A5gBEAPKIB8FAO7jElURRAVcAexgFiTAN5MKVigAcEkgG4R4FBHAgoDuQgE8KwAwNCCgB9cWgANQhCfDgAbktrO0dnSjcPL18xUKcY+MSrArEpWTkACh1c2IBKIotGa0arSQAzCjKqykkofSJCaooYcQQDNX04MYBRAA9BOBsYSS8y6oSGpqswyOjYigBeCk6KboozCgBfNY3No4POq+tzpnOgA=)

If you move the `null`-check plus exception *after* the `_hasValue` test, you get no warning:

```cs
public struct ThingE<T> where T : notnull
{
    private readonly bool _hasValue;
    private readonly T _value;
    
    ThingE(T value)
    {
        _hasValue = value is { };
         if (value is null) throw new Exception();
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

When processing `ThingE`, there's no warning. The exception guards the assignment to the `_value` field having asserted the parameter is not `null`. This is despite the `_hasValue` assignment implying that it can be. You're saying "from this point on its **definitely** not `null`". [SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQBMQGoA+BiAdgVwBtCJhC4ACOXU8igWACgABAJgEYnmBmC2BfAGMYFACoALAJa4A5gFEAPKIB8FAO7jElURRAVcAexgFiTAN5MKVigAcEkgG4R4FBHAgoDuQgE8KwAwNCCgB9cWgANQhCfDgAbktrO0dnSjcPL18xUKcY+MSrArEpWTkACh1c2IBKIotGa0bQ8KgovIoAXgoqykkoCjMKAF8EhqarSQAzCjKeij79IkJqihhxBAM1fTgtuQAPQTgbGEkvMurR8asQua6ey+shpiGgA=)

Remember that nullable annotations and constraints aren't a "real" part of the type system. Passing a nullable value or even `null` directly will not produce a compilation error, just a warning (unless of course `TreatWarningsAsErrors` is enabled). Also remember that your classes/methods expecting a non-`null` parameter **can be lied to**, either by

- Disabling (or just not enabling) `#nullable`
- Use of the `null`-forgiving operator, `!`
- Ignoring the warnings (as is my experience, very many people do)

You must still guard for `null`, typically checking and throwing **right-away**. This will help out flow analysis a ton. Flow analysis isn't perfect. There are a lot of patterns that should be detectable but aren't and the team is constantly working on making it better (C#9 had several improvements).

Anecdotally, when nullable reference types first came out, I was really unsure about whether we *really* needed to perform `null` tests if we were using non-`null` types. I had a quite lengthy conversation with Mads Torgersen at Microsoft Ignite back in 2019 following one of his C#8 presentations. He agreed with me that the subject could be unclear and that (at the time, at least) even the documentation didn't make it obvious. He stressed that unless the types were internal--so, part of your public API--that performing `null` guard pre-condition tests was still a necessity.